# pkill -P variable not working when running .sh under cron

Tags: bash, cron, pkill

I have a very simple `.sh` script to kill a process. The processes saves its PID to `pid2.txt`.

```
pkill -e -P $(cat pid2.txt)
exit
```

When I run this as `sudo ./myscript.sh` from the command line it works fine.

When run by cron as `*/2 * * * * /etc/mylocation/myscript.sh` it throws an error:

```
cat: pid2.txt: No such file or directory pkill: option requires an argument -- 'P'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the full path of `pid2.txt` in your script, it will then work

Comment: Great, I will add it as the answer

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the `-e` flag for `pkill`.  What does it do on your system, and what Unix are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. -e echoes which PID was killed.

Answer (score 1):

The cron job is not necessarily running with the same working directory that you happen to have in the interactive session.  This means that the file `pid2.txt` might not be available where you think it is. Change the script so that it uses an absolute path to the `pid2.txt` file.

You may also remove `exit` from the end of the script. It serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Add the full path of `pid2.txt` in your script, it will then work

**Explanation:**
cron jobs run in a very minimal environment, and since they're executed directly by crond without a shell (unless you force one to be created), the regular shell setup never happens. Hence you need to explicitly specify path of all files, scripts being called by cron

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs like was previous stated do not have the same environment variables (derived from `profile` and `bashrc` scripts) and most often should not.

To get around this I tend to append `--login` to the `#!/bin/bash` in order to get the same variables (path to binaries and libs) etc.

Example below would allow `pkill` to function under `cron`:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
pkill -e -P $(`cat /home/userid/pid2.txt`)
```